# What happens when you borrow from a temporary peekable iterator?

Tags: rust

This code reads a line from stdin and I want to split it.

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn example() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");
    let mut parts = input.trim().split_whitespace();
    let args = parts;
    let new_dir = args.peekable().peek().unwrap();
    println!("{}", new_dir);
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:8:19
   |
8  |     let new_dir = args.peekable().peek().unwrap();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                   |
   |                   temporary value does not live long enough
9  |     println!("{}", new_dir);
10 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

I understand that this means that `args.peekable()` creates a temporary value and `println!("{}", new_dir);` borrows that value.

I can not figure out where the temporary value is. I thought the borrowed value is from `args`, which won't be dropped here.

What really happens in `args.peekable().peek().unwrap();`?

Comment: Have you looked at the function signatures for [`peekable()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) ajd [`peek()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek)? The [source for `peekable()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#768) may also be useful. TL;DR: `peekable()` creates a `Peakable`, which `peek()` tries to borrow.

Answer (score 1):

> I can not figure out where the temporary value is

It's the result of `args.peekable()`, as the compiler highlights in the error message. [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) returns a [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html). The code then calls [`peek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek), which returns a reference to something inside the iterator:

```
pub fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&<I as Iterator>::Item>
```

To fix it, do as the compiler suggests:

> consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime

```
let mut x = args.peekable();
let new_dir = x.peek().unwrap();
```